# Retrofit with rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit on Android and I want to use RxJava.

Using only Retrofit was fine but with RxJava is kind of difficult for me.

Could you tell me what to do?

I wrote a interface like below but I'm not sure what option I should use at ???????????

Thanks in advance.

```
@GET("users")
Observable<??????????????> getUserById (@Query("id") int id);

@GET("users")
Observable<??????????????> getUserByName (@Query("name") String name);

@GET("users")
Observable<??????????????> getAllUsers ();
```

Comment: Actually what do you need? you are using it correct actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have wrtten, you have an experience with `Retrofit`. Normally your network call would return `Call<{type}>`, where type is the object you return from API.

Here you just replace `Call` with `Observable`. So your functions would look probably like:

```
@GET("users")
Observable<User> getUserById (@Query("id") int id);

@GET("users")
Observable<User> getUserByName (@Query("name") String name);

@GET("users")
Observable<List<User>> getAllUsers ();
```

The tutorial on how to use `RxJava` with `Retrofit` can be found [here](http://randomdotnext.com/retrofit-rxjava/)

Comment: Thanks Zagorski. It's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(YOUR API URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
                .build();
```

and add

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.1'
```

to gradle.

[Here](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/rxandroid-and-retrofit-2-0-66dc52725fff#.7esayuywe) is a Reference example